# How hide part of an php page until form is submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I made this script in php but I need hide the two last tables until "Procurar uma Letra" is clicked.. How I do that?
Or maybe if `$_POST[letra]` is *null* define it to "EmptyLetter" Word or something else...

I tried a couple of things but didn't worked.
How can I do that??

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm(form) {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["nome"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Nome a Inserir, deve ser preenchido");
        return false;
    }

    var y = document.forms["myForm"]["sexo"];
    if ( ( y[0].checked == false ) && ( y[1].checked == false ) ) {
        alert ( "Por favor escolha: Nome Masculino ou Feminino" ); 
        return false;

    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>BASE DE DADOS DE NOMES PR&Oacute;PRIOS</h1>
<br>
<h3>Enviar um nome para a base de dados</h3>

<form name="myForm" action="insert.php" onsubmit="return validateForm(this.form)" method="post">
Nome a inserir: <input type="text" name="nome" /><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="m" /> Nome Masculino&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="sexo" value="f" /> Nome Feminino <br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
Ir para a letra:    <input type="text" name="letra" />
<input type="submit" value="Procurar Letra">
</form>

<br><br><br>

</body>
</html>




<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database ="nomes";

$con=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

$masculinos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE sexo = 'm';");
$femininos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE sexo = 'f';");
$letramasculinos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'm';");
$letrafemininos = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT nome FROM nomes WHERE nome LIKE '$_POST[letra]%' AND sexo = 'f';");

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Nomes Masculinos</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($masculinos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Nomes Femininos</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($femininos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1'>";

echo "<br><br><br>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($letramasculinos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

echo "<table style='display: inline-block;' width='150px' border='1'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($letrafemininos))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><center>" . $row['nome'] . "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: add condition if(isset($_POST['submit'])  and add the two tables inside of it.

Comment: @Yair.R Thanks it worked, but i had to add `name="submit"` to my form... and not `(isset($_POST['submit'])` but `(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the resolved code so everyone can see:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     //tables will shown only after submitted
}
```

And also the submit form input must be declared like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: in my case: ```<input type="submit" value="Procurar Letra" name="submit">```

Comment: If you want to submit this form using JavaScript, you need to rename from "submit" to something else

Answer (score 1):

PHP [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php) gives you the answer as follows:

```
<?php if ($expression == true): ?>
  This will show if the expression is true.
<?php else: ?>
  Otherwise this will show.
<?php endif; ?>
```

> In this example PHP will skip the blocks where the condition is not
>   met, even though they are outside of the PHP open/close tags, PHP
>   skips them according to the condition since the PHP interpreter will
>   jump over blocks contained within a condition what is not met. For
>   outputting large blocks of text, dropping out of PHP parsing mode is
>   generally more efficient than sending all of the text through echo or
>   print.

This is known as, "Escaping from HTML". You can put the `$_POST[]` in the conditional.